# Prove the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is an equality if the vectors are linearly dependent.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is as follows: For any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $$|x^Ty|\leq||x||_2\cdot||y||_2$$
Equality is satisfied if and only if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

**My Attempt**

First, notice that $|x^Ty|=||x||_2||y||_2\cos(\theta)$. Then, the inequality becomes
$$|x^Ty|=||x||_2||y||_2\cos(\theta)\leq||x||_2\cdot||y||_2$$
Now note that $|\cos(\theta)|\leq1$ for all values $\theta$. Hence, the inequality holds.

Now to prove that equality holds if and only if the vectors $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

In the first direction, for the inequality to become an equality, we must have that $|\cos(\theta)|=1$. This only happens for $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$. This implies that the two vectors must be parallel with each other, or in other words, they must be linearly dependent. In the other direction, if the two vectors are linearly dependent, then they are scalar multiples of each other. This implies that both vectors point in the same (or opposite) direction (i.e. $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$). Then $|\cos(\theta)|=1$, and so we have equality.

I feel that my explanation for the equality part is inadequate. Could I get some verification on this? Thank you

Comment: $|x^Ty|=||x||_2||y||_2 |\cos(\theta)|$, both sides must be non-negative. Other than that, looks fine to me.

Comment: The first line of your "proof" is meaningless. In fact we can write $|x^Ty|=||x||_2||y||_2\cos(\theta)$ only because of C-S. That equality is the *definition*, not a *statement*. We can call the quotient $|x^Ty|/(||x||_2||y||_2)$  $\cos(\theta)$ only because it is $\le 1$.

In the second part, it is easier and cleaner to just assume that $y=cx$ for a constant $c$ and see that the equality is true.

Comment: Here is a proof for more general inner product spaces: https://math.ucr.edu/~res/math133/fall07/geometrynotes1insert1.pdf

Comment: @markvs I assume OP is working in the Euclidean case, not general inner product spaces. In this case, the cosine identity is simply a corollary of law of cosines, not just a redefinition of CS.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Law of cosines is for $n=2$.

Comment: @markvs No, it's not just for $n=2$. See this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product

Comment: @markvs in any case, more dimensions geometrically is identical to two dimensions since  two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are always coplanar.

Comment: In your proof, how do you define $\cos(\theta)$ for a pair of vectors?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio The fact that $x^Ty$ is the dot product in the plane spanned by $x$ and $y$ needs a proof and is not easier than what the OP is trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

The statement holds for abstract inner product spaces $(V,\langle .,.\rangle )$. In your case $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\langle u,v\rangle = u^Tv$. We can show it in this particular case:

Suppose $u,v$ are nonzero. We have that $(u-av)^T(u-av)=0$ only if $u=av$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. In general

$$\begin{aligned}0\leq (u-av)^T(u-av) &=u^Tu -2au^Tv+a^2v^Tv
\end{aligned}$$

Set $a=(u^Tu)/(u^Tv)$ and we get $(u^Tv)^2\leq (u^Tu)(v^Tv)$. So we get the equality only if $u=av$. On the other hand, if $u=av$, substitute it in the inequality and you get the equality.